# Extracting JSON response and putting them inside a customize JSON

Tags: arrays, api, jmeter, response, jmeter-5.0

Hi can anyone help me how to simulate this scenario. Thank you so much in advance and your response is highly appreciated.

Example I have this response below

```
[{
        "agentid": "9f235146-394d-3200-bff4-ff820c7cdb8e",
        "os": "",
        "fqdn": "prf_loadtest-54"
    },
    {
        "agentid": "33777a51-8696-3c53-97ab-5944224ae5e4",
        "os": "",
        "fqdn": "prf_loadtest-389"
    },

    {
        "agentid": "b6e859d0-2fb4-307d-b3b6-a6daa0b58fc2",
        "os": "",
        "fqdn": "server-13-35-77-127.bos50.r.cloudfront.net"
    }
]
```

and I want to extract all fqdn prf_loadtest agentId and use it on this request below, take note the agentId is **DYNAMIC** so example if I extracted 1 or 2 and etc it will use sample request below

if 1 extracted agent id

```
[{
    "key": "9f235146-394d-3200-bff4-ff820c7cdb8e",
    "value": "AD SERVER"
}]
```

if 2 extracted agentid

```
[{
    "key": "9f235146-394d-3200-bff4-ff820c7cdb8e",
    "value": "AD SERVER"
}, {
    "key": "33777a51-8696-3c53-97ab-5944224ae5e4",
    "value": "AD SERVER"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def request = response.findAll { entry -> entry.fqdn.contains('loadtest') }.collect { id -> [key: id.agentid, value: 'AD SERVER'] }

vars.put('request', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString())
```

the generated request can be accessed as `${request}` where required.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)